# Cross-compiling a source (tslib) for Android image (Allwinner A20)

Tags: android, kernel, cross-compiling

I would like to know if it's possible to add this repo in a source of Android : https://github.com/kergoth/tslib to build it at the same time. There's not Android.mk file.

I would like to use it to calibrate a touchscreen

I have seen this one http://sourceforge.net/p/tslibonandroid/code/ci/master/tree/
but my touchscreen (eGalax) is not added

Thanks

**

### Edit:

** I have found another [repo](https://github.com/etmatrix/tslib) for Android, but I think my ARCH not works.
(Is it Android.mk I have to modify ?) I'm a newbie for cross-compiling, and C/C++ language in general.
I have tried to do that in the folder:

```
autoreconf -ivs
./configure --target=sun7i_android
```

After that I've tried to build my image.
Result:

```
Export includes file: hardware/tslib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/EXECUTABLES/ts_print_raw_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/EXECUTABLES/ts_test_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: hardware/tslib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/EXECUTABLES/ts_test_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/ts/plugins/dejitter_intermediates/import_includes
Export includes file: hardware/tslib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/ts/plugins/dejitter_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/sugar-lemaker/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/ts/plugins/input_intermediates/import_includes
```

The folder of output is not `/system/xbin/` but `/obj/EXECUTABLES/`

The start of the Android.mk is:

```
#
# This Makefile will build tslib with most of the plugins
# and all the test applications
#

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

TSLIB_PLUGINDIR := /system/lib/ts/plugins

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        src/ts_attach.c \
        src/ts_close.c \
        src/ts_config.c \
        src/ts_error.c \
        src/ts_fd.c \
        src/ts_load_module.c \
        src/ts_open.c \
        src/ts_option.c \
        src/ts_parse_vars.c \
        src/ts_read.c \
        src/ts_read_raw.c
```

I think I have to change something but what ... that is the question

Comment: There is another (newer) [Android port of tslib](https://github.com/etmatrix/tslib/blob/master/BUILD-ANDROID). For building of it I'm using [this helper script](https://gist.github.com/nddrylliog/4688209) (needs to be adjusted) to run configure. Then I can run make within android build.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question by replacing in the Android.mk **all** these lines

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
```

by

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
```

and configure it with

```
autoreconf -ivs
./configure --enable-galax --target=sun7i --host=x86 --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --sysconfdir=/etc
```